# @Transactional for find and save method

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, database-connection

I have a method:

```
void method() {
    SomeEntity entity = someJpaRepository.findById(...);
    // some simple logic
    someJpaRepository.save(entity);
}
```

Does it make sense to put an annotation `@Transactional` over the method so that the logic for searching and saving the entity takes place in one connection to the database?

Or does it not make much sense and Spring or Hibernate will somehow be able to optimize the search and save itself?

Comment: Never trust. If performance is a concern, do you own testing and verify what is better for your application and use case. I'd suggest they should be in the same context though so that the 'save' operation doesn't have to re-read the SomeEntity instance from the database to determine the delta, but it entirely depends on concurrency of your application and what you are doing in between the read and write operations - a transaction will tie up a connection resource for the length of the transaction.